# how to found link click of multiple links using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a dynamic link ids, when ever i click on link i need to display a dynamic text area below the link, please explain how to do this using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation... here's an [example](http://blog.sudhirj.com/2008/11/event-delegation-works-like-charm.html).

You place a click handler on the div containing all the links. When this handler is called, you can get the element that the click was triggered on, check if its one of your links, and display your text under it.